# JSP EL String concatenation

Tags: jsp, el

How do I concatenate strings in EL?

I want to do something like this but it doesn't work:

```
${var1 == 0 ? 'hi' : 'hello ' + var2}
```

It throws an exception trying to cast `'hello'` to a `Double`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/296398/concatenate-strings-in-jsp-el

Comment: Just use 'hello'.concat(var2)

Answer (score 70, accepted):

The `+` operator always means numerical addition in JSP [*Expression Language*](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info). To do string concatenation you would have to use multiple adjacent EL expressions like `${str1}${str2}`.

If I read your example correctly this could be written as:

```
${var1 == 0 ? 'hi' : 'hello '}${var1 == 0 ? '' : var2}
```

---

### Edit

Another possibility would be to use [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info), which is longer but might be clearer if there is more text that depends on `var1`:

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${var1 == 0}">hi</c:when>
    <c:otherwise>hello <c:out value="${var2}"/></c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

The `c:out` might not be needed, depending on the JSP version.

Comment: I was hoping I wouldn't have to do that... repeating the condition every time.  My example is a simplification, in the real scenario I would have to repeat the example 3 times each time i want to do it :(

Answer (score 85):

Using java string concatenation works better.

```
#{var1 == 0 ? 'hi' : 'hello'.concat(var2)}
```

The benefit here is you can also pass this into a function, for instance

```
#{myCode:assertFalse(myVar == "foo", "bad myVar value: ".concat(myVar).concat(", should be foo"))}
```

Comment: Please note that this only works in the fresh new EL 2.2 and not in the older EL versions between 2001 and now.

Answer (score 44):

I know this is an old topic, but the answer to this question has changed in the past six months, and it's important to note that change, IMO (since I found this by Googling "el concatenate strings").

As of EL Expression 3.0 (public ballot approved August 2012, released with Java EE 7), a twist on the syntax the questioner originally used is now valid:

```
${var1 == 0 ? 'hi' : 'hello ' += var2}
```

There was much disagreement with the use of `+=` instead of `+`, but it is what it is. This will correctly evaluate and concatenate the strings as expected. You can also use the `cat` operator instead of the `+=` operator:

```
${var1 == 0 ? 'hi' : 'hello ' cat var2}
```

While this is now legal, note that you won't be able to use it until your web container (Tomcat, Jetty, GlassFish, etc.) releases a new version that supports Java EE 7/EL 3.0. This is expected sometime before the end of 2013, perhaps as early as the fall.

**Edited 2015-02-19** to note that the final operator was `+=` and not `+` as originally answered.

Comment: Great answer to see future! +1

Comment: Unfortunately this is not correct. At the last moment to much grievance of pretty much everyone they changed the operator from the completely logical "+" to the highly confusing "+=". I don't know what these guys were smoking :X

Comment: Dexter is correct. Thanks for the clarification. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Dear Nick Williams - how to concatenation work on your example:   Full Name: ${fn:escapeXml(user.lastName) += ', '
            += fn:escapeXml(user.firstName)}    . This bit of code is from your book(chap6 profile.jsp). I don't know - but error occures.

Answer (score 14):

One more alternative to all that was already mentioned:

```
<c:set var="hellovar2" value="hello ${var2}" />
${var1 == 0 ? 'hi' : hellovar2}
```