# NumberFormatException when trying to concatenate a String in EL

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, facelets, el

This is what I'm trying to generate:

```
<div class="marker" style="background:transparent url('/myApp/faces/javax.faces.resource/1.png?ln=images/map') no-repeat center top;"></div>
<div class="marker" style="background:transparent url('/myApp/faces/javax.faces.resource/2.png?ln=images/map') no-repeat center top;"></div>
<div class="marker" style="background:transparent url('/myApp/faces/javax.faces.resource/3.png?ln=images/map') no-repeat center top;"></div>

etc...
```

Here's my code:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{myBean.items}" var="item" varStatus="status">
    <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="marker" style="background:transparent url(#{resource['images/map:'+(status.index+1)+'.png']} no-repeat center top;"/>
</ui:repeat>
```

This is failing with a NumberFormatException because the EL interpreter attempts to convert "images/map" to a number. After searching quite a bit, I found that + is only for adding numbers. Any ideas how to achieve the desired results?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSP EL String concatenation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3189642/jsp-el-string-concatenation)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

EL does not recognize the `+` operator as String concatenation operator. The `+` operator is in EL ultimately to sum numbers only. You need to use `<ui:param>` to create another expression variable wherein you concatenate the parts by just inlining the EL expression in the value and then use it in the final expression instead.

```
<ui:repeat value="#{myBean.items}" var="item" varStatus="status">
    <ui:param name="key" value="images/map#{status.index + 1}.png" />
    <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="marker" style="background:transparent url(#{resource[key]} no-repeat center top;"/>
</ui:repeat>
```

*Note: if you were using JSP instead of Facelets, you'd have used JSTL `<c:set>` instead of Facelets `<ui:param>`.*

Comment: Just realised I hadn't up-voted this. I know it's old, but it's an answer I keep coming back to. :)

Comment: Superb, it's very useful @Baluc

Answer (score 4):

You can use `concat` function to concatenate strings in JSP EL. In your example that would be:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{myBean.items}" var="item" varStatus="status">
    <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="marker" style="background:transparent url(#{resource['images/map:'.concat( (status.index+1).concat('.png')]} no-repeat center top;"/>
</ui:repeat>
```

Comment: an ultimate solution for string concatenation in html, i hardly found this easy solution thanx to @Kalanj Djordje Djordje, I also updated my question which was un-answered for long.