# String concatenation for passing parameters in action clause

Tags: java, html

in an xhtml page, i need to pass a parameter to a bean method but i can't figure out how to pass a concatenated string having some literals and value from table column

i wrote

```
<p:commandButton action = "Combos.Students('T.StudentID=\''+result.STUDENTID+'\'')" />
```

but it gives error

java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "T.StudentID"

event if two strings are concatenated, same error occurs

```
<p:commandButton action = "Combos.Students('T.StudentID ' + ' abc ' )" />
```

The Method

```
    public void getValues (String s) {
        System.out.println("s : " + s);
    }
```

Call producing error (using a table column value or even any thing)

```
<p:commandButton action = "#{Combos.getValues('T.StudentID='+result.STUDENTNAME)}"/>
```

Call having no error

```
<p:commandButton action = "#{Combos.getValues('T.StudentID=')}"/>
```

Comment: Please share the action method's code. The error seems to be there, not in the jsf.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca i hv updated my question with reproduceable code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanx to @Kalanj Djordje Djordje in a post [NumberFormatException when trying to concatenate a String in EL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5993774/numberformatexception-when-trying-to-concatenate-a-string-in-el)
where not only i found the solution but also it was excellent. my final code is

```
<p:commandButton action = "Combos.Students('T.StudentID=\''.concat(result.FieldName)).concat('\''" />
```