# what's wrong in this el expression?

Tags: java, el

```
<ui:repeat value="#{admin.detailTypesList}" var="detailType">
<h:outputText value="#{admin.getDetailTypeTranslation('ContactDetailType_'+detailType)}"/>
</ui:repeat>
```

for the el expression:

```
#{admin.getDetailTypeTranslation('ContactDetailType_'+detailType)}
```

The parameter passed to `getDetailTypeTranslation` is `'ContactDetailType_'` (without the `detailType` value)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSP EL String concatenation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3189642/jsp-el-string-concatenation)

Comment: @McDowell not quite. This problem also requires the knowledge of using a el variable in a concatenation expression.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In EL, the `+` is exclusively a sum operator. You can use `<ui:param>` to create a new variable which exist of a string concatenated with an EL expression and then use the new variable instead.

```xml
<ui:repeat value="#{admin.detailTypesList}" var="detailType">
    <ui:param name="contactDetailType" value="ContactDetailType_#{detailType}" />
    <h:outputText value="#{admin.getDetailTypeTranslation(contactDetailType)}"/>
</ui:repeat>
```

Please note that this problem is not related to JSF, but to EL in general.

Answer (score 0):

jsf's EL doesn't really have the concat operation ('+'). You should write a function to do it or use a bean method.