# How to invoke an external library function on an object within a JSTL loop before outputting it?

Tags: java, jsp, loops, import, jstl

Let's say I have the following JSTL loop:

```
<c:forEach items="${foos}" var="foo" varStatus="status">
    <c:out value="${processedFoo}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

And let's say I have an external library `com.foo.processor` which contains a `ProcessorFactory` class with a `process` method.

How do I import this library and call the following code from inside the JSTL loop?

```
Foo processedFoo = com.foo.processor.ProcessorFactory.process(foo)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't. Putting a lot of logic in the JSP layer leads to an application that is difficult to maintain.

You could create your own tag library that [includes a custom function,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296398/concatenate-strings-in-jsp-el/296752#296752) but this sort of processing is best done by a servlet before forwarding the request to a JSP for rendering.