# Cannot convert abcdefg of type class java.lang.String to class [Ljava.lang.String;

Tags: jsp, jstl

I'm trying to put together a String in a tag-library like this:

```
<c:set var="columnText" value="${fn:join(columnText,'.pdf')}" />
<a href="${fn:join('http://host:8082/pdf/',columnText)}" >bla</a>
```

However this exception occurs:

> javax.el.ELException: Cannot convert abcedfg of type class java.lang.String to class [Ljava.lang.String;

'abcdefg' is the content of columnText at first.

Comment: The 2nd line makes no sense.  What is `columnText`?  What's the purpose of the 1st line, if you're not using the value it provides?

Comment: Removed the first line as it didn't make sense for this question.

Comment: columnText is an ordinary String.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you are trying to do the equivalent of

```
columnText = columnText + '.pdf'
```

but that is not the usage of `fn:join`. `join` [recieves an array and joins its elements](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_function_join.htm) using the second argument as a separator.

Try with

```
<c:set var="columnText" value="${columnText}.pdf"/>
```

By the way, if you wanted to put strings together you should have looked for help in concatenating strings, to find posts like this: [Concatenate strings in JSP EL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/296398/422353)