# JSTL Access Integer/Long key in Hash Map

Tags: java, hashmap, jstl, el

I am facing some problem in using EL in JSTL and not able to access Java Hash Map as I would like. I am aware that in EL the key, if Integer gets accessed as Long. I have following hash map definition that I am trying to access in JSTL -

```
Map<Long, Object> testMap = new HashMap<Long, Object>();
```

In JSP page, I need to check if the map contains a specific key or not. I attempt to do that by checking if not empty as following -

```
<c:if test='${ ! empty testMap[currObj.currVal]}'>
```

I also access the map's value for a key somewhere in the code like below -

```
<c:if test='${ testMapMap[5].data == 'something'}'>
```

Now the problem -

If i define my map above as `<Integer, Object>` then the first c:if works but second fails (as the second tries to access it as Long). However, if I define my map above as `<Long, Object>` the first if check always fails as it always recognizes it as empty but the second if statement where I check for the value works.

Is there any good way to make sure I access HashMap for both the if statements correctly? I will appreciate opinions.

Comment: Does `5L` work for the second one?

Comment: In the above example, the second one is correctly accessing it as Long so I did not need to put "L" at the end of the element to access the map.

Comment: Oh, sorry, read that backwards.

Comment: For checking that map contains key or not .Simple way to do that           <c:if test="${requestScope.map[3]==null}"> 
   <c:out value="Not A valid KEy"></c:out>
  </c:if>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is `currObj`? Can you redefine its `currVal` member as a `Long` (or `long`)?

---

A numeric literal (matching the `IntegerLiteral` production in the EL syntax) will be represented as a `Long`. The expression `currObj.currVal` evaluates to an `Integer`. A `Long` never `equals()` an `Integer`, so one expression must result in a different type.

Essentially, what you need is an explicit type conversion. Nothing like this is built into EL, but you could create a custom EL function to do it for you. This is a static function that you implement in Java, then describe in a TLD. Another answer of mine [gives an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/296752/3474) of the packaging. Here's what the function and its usage could look like in your case.

```
package com.y.taglib.core;

public final class CoercionUtil {

  public static Long toLong(Long n) {
    return n;
  }

}
```

The TLD would look like this:

```
<taglib xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-jsptaglibrary_2_0.xsd" version="2.0">
  <tlib-version>1.0</tlib-version>
  <short-name>x-c</short-name>
  <uri>http://dev.y.com/taglib/core/1.0</uri>
  <function>
    <description>Coerce to a java.lang.Long.</description>
    <display-name>long</display-name>
    <name>long</name>
    <function-class>com.y.taglib.core.CoercionUtil</function-class>
    <function-signature>java.lang.Long toLong(java.lang.Long)</function-signature>
  </function>
</taglib>
```

In your JSP:

```
<%@taglib uri="http://dev.y.com/taglib/core/1.0" prefix="my" %>
...
<c:if test='${ ! empty testMap[my:long(currObj.currVal)]}'>
```

The JSP engine takes care of the necessary type coercion (from the `Integer` result of `currVal` to the `Long` required by the `toLong()` method. Your method is there simply to indicate the required type; without it, the JSP engine sees the (erased) type of the argument of `testMap.get(Object)`, and doesn't see the need to perform any coercion since `Integer` is-an `Object`.

Comment: Unfortunately I am unable to redefine it as I am not the owner of it. The class is used by other external components as well. `currVal` in `currObj` returns Integer.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping to avoid doing this but I guess I do not have any other better way. Will mark your answer if I do not hear any better solution from anyone else. Appreciate your help.