# Accessing HashMap<Long,String> in JSP with Integer key no longer works

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, el, stripes

This code used to work fine, but I just overhauled a lot of the underlying Java code and now it no longer works. I have a bean with values:

```
<c:forEach items="${actionBean.appliedJobs}" var="aJob" varStatus="loop">
    ${aJob}
</c:forEach>
```

This prints out: `14513=APPLIED 14535=APPLIED 14515=APPLIED 14514=APPLIED`. appliedJobs is populated in Java as a `HashMap<Long, String>`. I also have code that accesses this array using a variable `jobId` which is of type Integer.

```
${jobId} //This prints correctly as 14513
${actionBean.appliedJobs[jobId]} //Prints nothing, is likely null
${actionBean.appliedJobs[14513]} //This prints correctly as APPLIED
```

The third line in the above block prints fine because 14513 is interpreted as a Long, I think. I'm aware of the Long/Integer jstl issues as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924451/el-access-a-map-value-by-integer-key) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10418624/jstl-access-integer-long-key-in-hash-map), but the fact that this code used to work is what's throwing me off.

EDIT: For now, I've created a getter() for jobId that returns a Long jobId instead of Integer jobId and that has circumvented the issue, but I'd still like to know the root cause.

Comment: did you get the root cause of it ?

Comment: @iAmLearning No I don't think I ever did, and I don't have access to this code anymore.

Answer (score -1):

You can do the following to iterate through all elements of a Map  :

```
 <c:forEach items="${actionBean.appliedJobs}" var="aJob" varStatus="loop">
            ${aJob.value}
            ${aJob.key}
 </c:forEach>
```

Comment: `javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'value' not found on type javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.LoopTagSupport$1Status`

Comment: my bad..I had used the varStatus variable instead of var. try it using aJob.value

Comment: Prints: `APPLIED APPLIED APPLIED APPLIED`

Comment: Which is exopected is Applied is the value..if you want to print the key use aJob.key

Comment: I'm using the forEach as a debugging tool, the real problem occurs in `${actionBean.appliedJobs[jobId]}`. Read my edit for more info, I'm looking to identify a root cause.

Comment: Ultimately the function `return new HashMap<Integer, String>();`, populated using `map.put(jobId,"APPLIED")` where jobId is of type Integer

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48624/discussion-between-kakarot-and-j-l)