# Error using EL in JSP: "The function contains must be used with a prefix when a default namespace is not specified"

Tags: jsp, jstl, el

In my jsp page I am specifying:

```
<c:choose>
line 1: <c:when test="${com.community_classification_id.contains('1')}">
            <input type="checkbox" id="by_invitation1"   name="invitaion" value="1" checked="true">By Invitation<span style="padding-left:28px"></span>
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
            <input type="checkbox" id="by_invitation1"   name="invitaion" value="1">By Invitation<span style="padding-left:28px"></span>
        </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

but @line no. 1 it gives me 500 error with

```
The function contains must be used with a prefix when a default namespace is not specified
```

I am not able to understand it. What is wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check this out: [JSTL fn:contains() function](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/tld-summary.html)

Used to find a String inside another one (I guess this is you are trying to achieve)

In your code:

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${fn:contains(com.community_classification_id, '1')}">
        <input type="checkbox" id="by_invitation1" name="invitaion" value="1" checked="true">By Invitation<span style="padding-left:28px"></span>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <input type="checkbox" id="by_invitation1" name="invitaion" value="1">By Invitation<span style="padding-left:28px"></span>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Don't forget to include the taglib in your JSP to use it:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>
```

Comment: I don't understand... my answer helped you but you accepted the other one? It's a mistake? XD

Answer (score 1):

You can use your static method in EL (which I assume `com.community_classification_id.contains` is) but first you have to define custom EL function.

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6396886/708434) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/296752/708434) which shows how to create and use EL functions in JSP. Then just remember to import your taglib and use your static method with prefix like shown in those answers.